# 'Re-select' select depending on other select (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I've filled my select dropdowns with json-data. The content of the selects depend on the selection of the selects and radio's before it. Is it possible to 'reset' all selects when I decide to choose another radio button?

I am using the following code:

```
function changeCustomerType(value) {
    selectedCustomerType = value;

    if(typeof dateTypeCol === 'undefined') {
        dateTypeCol = temp[value];
        console.log(dateTypeCol);
    } else {
        dateTypeCol = '';
        yearCol = '';
        console.log(yearCol);
        dateTypeCol = temp[value];
        console.log(dateTypeCol);
    }
}

function changeDateType(value) {
    console.log(selectedCustomerType);
    $(dateFieldset).show();
    yearLabel.show();
    selectedDateType = value;

    switch(selectedDateType) {
    case 'Weekend':
        $(yearSelect).selectedIndex = 0;
        $(monthSelect).hide();
        $(dateSelect).hide();
        break;
    case 'Midweek':
        $(yearSelect).selectedIndex = 0;
        $(monthSelect).hide();
        $(dateSelect).hide();
        break;
    case 'Week':
        $(yearSelect).selectedIndex = 0;
        $(monthSelect).hide();
        $(dateSelect).hide();
        break
    }

    if(typeof yearCol !== 'undefined') {
        yearCol = '';
        $(yearSelect).empty();

        yearCol = dateTypeCol[value];
        console.log(yearCol);

        $.each(yearCol, function(key, value) {
            $(yearSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    } else {
        yearCol = '';
        $(yearSelect).empty();

        yearCol = dateTypeCol[value];
        console.log(yearCol);

        $(yearSelect).append('<option value></option>');
        $.each(yearCol, function(key, value) {
            $(yearSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    }

}

function getMonths(year) {
    selectedYear = year;
    $(dateSelect).hide();
    $(monthSelect).show();

    if(typeof monthCol === 'undefined') {
        monthCol = yearCol[year];
        console.log(monthCol);

        $.each(monthCol, function(key, value) {
            $(monthSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    } else {
        monthCol = '';
        $(monthSelect).empty();

        monthCol = yearCol[year];
        console.log(monthCol);

        $(monthSelect).append('<option value></option>');
        $.each(monthCol, function(key, value) {
            $(monthSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    }
}

function getDates(month) {

    switch(selectedDateType) {
    case 'Weekend':
        $(dateSelect).show();
        break;
    case 'Midweek':
        $(dateSelect).show();
        break;
    case 'Week':
        $(dateSelect).show();
        break
    }

    //console.log(selectedCustomerType, selectedDateType, selectedYear, month);

    if(typeof dateCol === 'undefined') {
        dateCol = monthCol[month];
        console.log(dateCol);

        $.each(dateCol, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value);
            $.each(value, function(key1, value1) {
                if(key1 == 'id') {
                    id = value1;
                };
            });
            $.each(value, function(key2, value2) {
                if(key2 == 'startDate') {
                    $(dateSelect).append('<option value=' + id + '>' + value2 + '</option>');
                };
            });
        });
    } else {
        dateCol = '';
        $(dateSelect).empty();

        $.each(dateCol, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value);
            $.each(value, function(key1, value1) {
                if(key1 == 'id') {
                    id = value1;
                };
            });
            $(monthSelect).append('<option value></option>');
            $.each(value, function(key2, value2) {
                if(key2 == 'startDate') {
                    $(dateSelect).append('<option value=' + id + '>' + value2 + '</option>');
                };
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Current situation:

[image: current situation]

It's a bit of a mess now, need to nicen it up a bit after this.
If any other information is required, please ask! New to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS I know the if-statements are really redundant, need to nicen that up, was just a quick fix.

Comment: Do you have any listeners set up for the change event of the radios? Something like this: $("input[name='radio']").change(function() {}) after the customer types are initialized ?

Comment: An onclick and onchange on the radio buttons for 'customerType' and 'dateType'. If that's what you mean?

Comment: yes - do those handlers get called at all? Or are they called and they don't reset the selects?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="customerType" onclick="changeCustomerType(this.value)" data-entityname="CustomerType" value="1">" One of these on 'dateType' radio as well. Triggering the functions 'change...' from code.

Comment: First: are you sure yearSelect selects what you want? Something like this should work: $([name=yourSelectNameHere]). If that points to the right element, try this: $(yearSelect).prop('selectedIndex',0);

Comment: Yes, but the 'selectedIndex' won't work. Because if I select 'Weekend' after i've selected 'week' for instance, other years should become available in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I can get the required result by hiding and showing the selects.
The code is still a bit messy, but for people with the same problem, look up : http://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
function changeCustomerType(value) {
    selectedCustomerType = value;

    dateTypeRadio.prop('checked', false);
    $(dateFieldset).hide();
    yearLabel.hide();

    if(typeof dateTypeCol === 'undefined') {
        dateTypeCol = temp[value];
        console.log(dateTypeCol);
    } else {
        dateTypeCol = '';
        yearCol = '';
        console.log(yearCol);
        dateTypeCol = temp[value];
        console.log(dateTypeCol);
    }
}

function changeDateType(value) {
    selectedDateType = value;

    $(dateFieldset).hide();
    yearLabel.hide();

    if(typeof(dateTypeCol) == 'undefined'){
        dateTypeRadio.prop('checked', false);
        $(dateFieldset).hide();
        console.log('Selecteer eerst Soort Groep.');
        return;
    } else {
        $(dateFieldset).show();
        console.log('Groepsoort gekozen, geef datumselectie weer..');
    }
```